# Having trouble understanding question about sorting 2d arrays

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, 2d

Has anyone ever come across a question like this?

I was asked to: "sort a 2d array (csv table format) by column using the first column as the **primary key** (?). And if you get ties in the first column, those rows that are tied need to be sorted by the second listed column.

sample input/ output:

```
 20.0     1.0       2.0    10.0
 18.0     2.0       4.0     9.0
 16.0     3.0       6.0     8.0
 14.0     4.0       8.0     7.0 
 12.0     5.0      10.0     6.0
 10.0     6.0      12.0     5.0
  8.0     7.0      14.0     4.0
  6.0     8.0      16.0     3.0
  4.0     9.0      18.0     2.0 
  2.0    10.0      20.0     1.0
```

I have managed sort each column using insertion sort but the output looks different as I haven't managed to implement the sort using the first column as the primary key. What does this mean exactly? Should I swap values on the second column every time I do so on the first column? I am also not sure how to handle ties.

Comment: It would be easier to provide a relevant answer if you gave your current code... The rule is that you must not sort individual columns. You should instead store values in a 2D array (rows first) and then sort an array of pointer to rows. The comparison function should use values of first field (of the row) and second one if there are ties in the first column.

Comment: It is very common to sort data depending on more than one property. If you want to sort a list of people by age, where you have year, month and day in separate fields, you will need to use year as first key, month as second and day as third key. It is important to swap a whole set of data if your compare function detects you need to swap, not only the field with the key.

Comment: That is not a proper set of sample data. If the question explicitely mentions using multiple keys in case of a tie, there should be at least one such case included.

Comment: Sort the array treating each row as an inseparable record. If row j is “less than” row i but i < j, then swap all of row i with all of row j. “Less than” is determined by comparing the elements in yhe first column, then, if needed, the elements in the second, and so on,

Comment: Please add your code to show us how you get the data and what you have tried so far. Hint: Separate comparing function from sorting function. Create a `compare` function as for `qsort` and create a `sort` function that implements the sorting mechanism and calls the `compare` function